# Is netsuite token will expire when I uninstall the bundle?

Tags: netsuite

I've created a bundle with integration & script in one account (A). Then I installed it in another account (B). Now I created an token in installed account (B) using bundle integration's consumer key & account (B) credentials. 
By using that token I can able to access account (B) contents.

My questions are,

1. Whenever I uninstall that bundle from account B, then it also expire my token that I've created using bundle integration ?
2. How many tokens can be created for an account, Is there is any limitation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I will try to reply your questions:

1. I do not think the token will expire when you uninstall your bundle, however I do not think the token will be useful anymore since the integration application will probably not exist anymore, so the consumer key and consumer secret used by the token will not longer work.
2. I am not aware of any limitation for the amount of tokens record created in an account.

It would be useful for you: 
**Tokens created in your production account are not copied to your sandbox during a refresh. To test token-based authentication in your sandbox, you must create tokens in the sandbox account. Each time your sandbox is refreshed, you will need to create new tokens in the sandbox**

[Source from suiteanswer](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/82313)